# How can I enumerate the clipboard formats

Tags: wpf, clipboard

With WPF, I can get data in a given format from the clipboard:

object test = Clipboard.GetGata (format);

How can I enumerate the list of formats present in the clipboard?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the `IDataObject` class.

```
IDataObject content = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
string [] formats = clipContent.GetFormats();
```

Comment: Thanks. This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<String> dataFormats = typeof(DataFormats).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                                .Select(f => f.Name)
                                .ToList();
```

this should give you all the Fields from [DataFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats_fields.aspx)

```
List<String> dataFormatsInClipboard = 
             dataFormats.Where( df => Clipboard.ContainsData(df) )
             .ToList();
```

will give you just the ones that match the clipboard.

Comment: Nope, DataFormats contains a list of static formats. I am looking for the list of formats _present in the clipboard_.

Comment: @user Check out my edit. see if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: the `Clipboard.GetData()` documentation says `Parameters
format
Type: System.String
The format of the data to retrieve. See DataFormats for predefined formats.`

Comment: So if it's not in the predefined like, what kind of formats do you have?

Comment: What I am looking for would somehow encapsulate EnumClipboardFormats